# Error while refreshing project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'am refreshing my project in force.com ide(Eclipse) and getting an error "Unable to refresh Resource TLS v1.1" error .

Iam using Helious and java version 1.7 . What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: You need to use Java 7 with TLSv1.0 turned off or Java 8. See the prerequisite section of [Force.com IDE Installation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation). Support for TLSv1.0 is being turned off in orgs as described in [Salesforce disabling TLS 1.0](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000221207).

Comment: thanks Keith , but I have only Java 8 in my system and updated the eclipse.ini file as mentioned in the force,com ISE Installation . But still I'am facing the same issue.